# HDFS from Java - Specifying the User

Tags: java, security, authentication, hadoop, hdfs

I'm happily connecting to HDFS and listing my home directory:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://hadoop:8020");
conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> ri = fs.listFiles(fs.getHomeDirectory(), false);
while (ri.hasNext()) {
    LocatedFileStatus lfs = ri.next();
    log.debug(lfs.getPath().toString());
}
fs.close();
```

What I'm wanting to do now though is connect as a specific user (not the whois user). Does anyone know how you specify which user you connect as?

Comment: hi i tried this code to connect to a remote hdfs instance but i get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation

Comment: do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I asked this question more than 2 years ago. Hadoop has moved on a long way since then. As far as exact implementations go, things are quite possibly done in a different way now.

Comment: oh ok, makes sense. however if you are still developing in hadoop and are doing something similar, please let me know. i have been struggling with this for a while. i have also asked a couple of questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610916/how-to-connect-to-remote-hdfs and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681940/cannot-connect-to-remote-hdfs

Comment: if you get some time, please try to post an answer. i would be eternally grateful. thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As soon as I see this is done through `UserGroupInformation` class and `PrivilegedAction` or `PrivilegedExceptionAction`. Here is sample code to connect to remote HDFS 'like' different user ('hbase' in this case). Hope this will solve your task. In case you need full scheme with authentication you need to improve user handling. But for SIMPLE authentication scheme (actually no authentication) it works just fine.

```
package org.myorg;

import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;

public class HdfsTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            UserGroupInformation ugi
                = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hbase");

            ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {

                public Void run() throws Exception {

                    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://1.2.3.4:8020/user/hbase");
                    conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hbase");

                    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

                    fs.createNewFile(new Path("/user/hbase/test"));

                    FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user/hbase"));
                    for(int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
                        System.out.println(status[i].getPath());
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I searched for hadoop configuration parameter settings and i don't get any useful explanations. Does hbase means user in conf.set. Where can i get all hadoop class explanations not only avail classes. Any links please?

Comment: `org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation` is key class here and it allows to specify 'remote user' through `createRemoteUser()`. So Hadoop cluster sees you as user you have specified nidependent of your local user. Of course this works only if your Hadoop cluster trusts you (SIMPLE authentication, actually none). With Kerberous you additionally will need to provide proofs.

Comment: i tried this but i get java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation

Comment: @AbtPst As you can see people actively use this and I have only 2 guesses for you: 1) Check exception stacktraace to isolate root cause. 2) Check your addresses / ports / paths. Maybe you just use wrong user name.

Comment: how would i get a list of correct usernames? please forgive me if this is a basic question but i am quite new to hadoop and unix

Comment: In face there is no single way: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correct, all you want is to get home directory of the user if specify and not the whois user.

In you configuration file, set your homedir property to user/${user.name}. Make sure you have a system property named user.name

This worked in my case.

I hope this is what you want to do, If not add a comment.

Comment: I'm actually wanting to browse the entire HDFS file system, like what Hue does. i.e. be the hdfs user.