# Cannot connect to remote HDFS from Windows

Tags: java, windows, maven, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

i am trying to connect to a remote HDFS instance as

```
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://hostName:8020");
        conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> ri = fs.listFiles(fs.getHomeDirectory(), false);
        while (ri.hasNext()) {
            LocatedFileStatus lfs = ri.next();
            //log.debug(lfs.getPath().toString());
        }

        fs.close();
```

here are my Maven dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-examples</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and here is the result of hadoop version command on my remote node

```
hadoop version
Hadoop 2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557
```

but i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:217)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2624)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2634)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2651)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
at filecheck.HdfsTest.main(HdfsTest.java:21)
```

and this is the line that causes the error

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

any idea why this might be happening?

**After trying Manjunath's answer**

here is what i get

```
ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2802)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
    at filecheck.HdfsTest.main(HdfsTest.java:27)
15/11/16 09:48:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname  from hdfs://hostName:8020 is not a valid DFS filename.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$000(DistributedFileSystem.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$DirListingIterator.<init>(DistributedFileSystem.java:940)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$DirListingIterator.<init>(DistributedFileSystem.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:872)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listLocatedStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:1694)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$6.<init>(FileSystem.java:1787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listFiles(FileSystem.java:1783)
    at filecheck.HdfsTest.main(HdfsTest.java:29)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: i have added the stacktrace and line of code that causes the error

Answer (score 1):

My HDFS client code code uses hadoop-hdfs also requires:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I use the Hortonworks repository:

```
    <repository>
        <id>repo.hortonworks.com</id>
        <name>Hortonworks HDP Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
```

I think you're picking up the wrong version of FileSystem.

Comment: thanks, but if i do as you suggest, i get The method listFiles(Path, boolean) is undefined for the type FileSystem

Answer (score 1):

The exception is occurring in `FileSystem.java`, in `getScheme()` method, which simply throws `UnsupportedOperationException` exception.

```
  public String getScheme() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented by the " + getClass().getSimpleName() + " FileSystem implementation");
  }
```

It is calling `getScheme()` method of `FileSystem` class, instead of calling `getScheme()` method from `DistributedFileSystem` class.

The `getScheme()` method of `DistributedFileSystem` class returns:

```
@Override
  public String getScheme() {
    return HdfsConstants.HDFS_URI_SCHEME;
  }
```

So, to overcome this problem, you need to change the "FileSystem.get(conf)" statement, as shown below:

```
DistributedFileSystem fs = (DistributedFileSystem) FileSystem.get(conf);
```

**EDIT:**

I tried out the program and it worked perfectly fine for me. In fact, it works with and without casting.
Following is my code (only difference is, I am setting recursive listing to "true"):

```
package com.hadooptests;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.RemoteIterator;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HDFSConnect {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://machine:8020");
        conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
        DistributedFileSystem fs = null;
        try {
            fs = (DistributedFileSystem) FileSystem.get(conf);
            RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> ri;
            ri = fs.listFiles(new Path("hdfs://machine:8020/"), true);
            while (ri.hasNext()) {
                LocatedFileStatus lfs = ri.next();
                System.out.println(lfs.getPath().toString());
            }
            fs.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest> 
                      <mainClass>com.hadooptests.HDFSConnect
                    </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I ran the program as:

```
java -cp "%CLASSPATH%;hadooptests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" com.hadooptests.HDFSConnect
```

where CLASSPATH is set to: 
`.;%HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop\;%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\common\*;%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\common\lib\*;%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs\*;%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*;%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*;%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*;%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\tools\*;%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\tools\lib\*;%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\yarn\*;%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*`

Some of the output, I got:

```
hdfs://machine:8020/app-logs/machine/logs/application_1439815019232_0001/machine.corp.com_45454
hdfs://machine:8020/app-logs/machine/logs/application_1439815019232_0002/machine.corp.com_45454
hdfs://machine:8020/app-logs/machine/logs/application_1439817471006_0002/machine.corp.com_45454
hdfs://machine:8020/app-logs/machine/logs/application_1439817471006_0003/machine.corp.com_45454
```

**EDIT 2:**

My environment:

Hadoop 2.7.1 on Windows.

I installed HDP 2.3.0, which deploys Hadoop 2.7.1

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check. It works fine for me.

Comment: thanks i will check and confirm. by the way, i am running the program from eclipse and i am not executing it via the java -jar command. will that make a difference?

Comment: Not sure. I never used Eclipse.

Comment: note that i am running this code from windows but i am trying to connect to a remote hdfs instance running on a linux box

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows.

Comment: ok, please tell me what have you installed on windows? which hadoop binaries and environment variables need to be set?

Comment: looks like i mistakenly edited your answer instead of the question. please reject the edit to your answer. i have updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95258/discussion-between-manjunath-ballur-and-abtpst).

Comment: un fortunately, i cannot use chat at my workplace. can you please edit your answer to include exactly what you installed/unzipped on widows? then i can compare with what i have.